# How to use js function with mongo-go-driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb, go

The goal is to implement counter field (kind of auto increment) in some collection.
 I am able to save this function via mongoshell:

```
> db.system.js.save({
 _id: "getValueForNextSequence",
 value : function(fieldName){
    var sequenceDoc = db.counters.find({sequenceName: fieldName }).toArray()[0];
  if (sequenceDoc.sequence > 9998){
     sequenceDoc =  db.counters.findAndModify({
      query:{sequenceName: fieldName },
      update: {$set:{sequence:1000}},
      new:true
    });
  }else {
    sequenceDoc =  db.counters.findAndModify({
      query:{sequenceName: fieldName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence:1}},
      new:true
    });
  }
  return sequenceDoc.sequence;
}
})
```

I have `counters` collection where I store data for `getValueForNextSequence`:

`{fieldName: "shotID" , sequence : 0 }`

and then call it(again from the shell):

```
 db.loadServerScripts()

> db.STORE.insert({
... "shortID":getValueForNextSequence("shortID"),
... "item_short_name": "DEF",
... "specification": "book",
... "category": "fictional",
... "seller": "best_buy",
... "network": "XYZ",
... "plan": "regular"
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

But I cannot understand how can I do the same with the official go-mongo-driver.

Comment: In your Go application, can't you just write `getValueforNextSequence()` and invoke the function before you insert ? If you have issues with this approach, please provide what have you tried in Go. Also, worth noting that your method of `findAndModify` may conflict with other concurrent processes.

Comment: I want to do this inside mongoDB container because there are multiple pods that have access to the DB.
And about the function itself, I've just copied it from the mongoDB [website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm)

Comment: Are you wanting something similar to a stored procedure for `getValueForNextSequence()` ? Is there a reason not to utilise ObjectId ?

Comment: Yes, I thought to use something similar to sql procedure.
There are business requirements, that specify the format of the field, frequency of the repetition and user readability, I thought about ObjectId field, but it cannot satisfy all necessary options.